What is the correct format to ping ip address range with some extra single ip addresses using nmap
I'm struggling with the usage of nmap.
I would like to ping IP addresses in the range, say, 192.168.178.110-192.168.178.130 but also the single IP 192.168.178.1.
Therefore I execute:
nmap -sn 192.168.178.110-130 192.168.178.1

Giving me:
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-04-19 10:16 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.119
Host is up (0.00076s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.120
Host is up (0.0021s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.121
Host is up (0.0020s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.125
Host is up (0.0019s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.127
Host is up (0.0017s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.129
Host is up (0.0015s latency).
Nmap done: 22 IP addresses (6 hosts up) scanned in 2.21 seconds

However, executing:
nmap -sn 192.168.178.110-130 192.168.178.0 192.168.178.1

Gives me:
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-04-19 10:23 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.119
Host is up (0.00080s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.120
Host is up (0.0022s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.121
Host is up (0.0021s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.125
Host is up (0.0018s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.127
Host is up (0.0016s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.129
Host is up (0.0014s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.1
Host is up (0.0015s latency).
Nmap done: 23 IP addresses (7 hosts up) scanned in 1.41 seconds

So, in the first attempt, the IP 192.168.178.1 is not listed, despite it was included in the command line.
In the second attempt, I add the superfluous IP 192.168.178.0, and then it lists me the IP 192.168.178.1.
Why is this so?
I'm not interested in the IP 192.168.178.0.
To me, it appears like a detour to ping that IP in order to get information about the reachability of IP 192.168.178.1.
Update:
Using nmap -vv ... shows that nmap is able to parse the given command line in both cases. However, the result for the IP 192.168.178.1 is still inconsistent.
nmap -vv -sn 192.168.178.110-130 192.168.178.1: 
[...] 
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.1 [host down, received no-response], 


nmap -vv -sn 192.168.178.110-130 192.168.178.0 192.168.178.1: 
[...] 
Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.0 [host down, received net-unreach] Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.1 Host is up, received syn-ack (0.0012s latency).


From the docs (https://nmap.org/book/man-target-specification.html):

Everything on the Nmap command-line that isn't an option (or option argument) is treated as a target host specification.  ... >Nmap accepts multiple host specifications on the command line, and they don't need to be the same type.


I've got a typo in the second example. I accidentally wrote  nmap -sn  192.168.178.100-129 192.168.178.0 192.168.178.1. it must be nmap -sn  192.168.178.110-129 192.168.178.0 192.168.178.1. I tested this again, with the corrected command. The result was the same, except nmap reported a scan of 22 IP addresses, instead. Edited the question thereof.

I now installed nmap via snap and got version 7.94, too. The problem remains the same. The IP 192.168.178.1 is only listed in the results, if I also specify the IP 192.168.178.0.

The example in the man-page uses a semi-colon: scanme.nmap.org, 192.168.0.1; 10.0.0-255.1-254.

If I use that semicolon, nmap pings the IP 192.168.178.1 but not the other IPs. 192.168.178.110-130: Befehl nicht gefunden.

@harrymc This does not look like code, probably examples written in ordinary language. The semicolon is a command terminator in most shells in Linux.

This then strangely looks like a bug or missing documentation.

What is the output of nmap -vv -sn … in both cases? Does the first attempt report anything about 192.168.178.1?

nmap -vv -sn 192.168.178.110-130 192.168.178.1: [...] Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.1 [host down, received no-response],  nmap -vv -sn 192.168.178.110-130 192.168.178.0 192.168.178.1: [...] Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.0 [host down, received net-unreach] Nmap scan report for 192.168.178.1 Host is up, received syn-ack (0.0012s latency).

As a consequence I would say, nmap was able to parse the syntax and tried to ping the IPs 192.168.178.0 respectively 192.168.178.1, too.

That then probably means that the connection from the machine to your router is dodgy ...
